# Setting up python application on fastcomet

Tags: python, wsgi

Folowing a request for a html page from a client, my python application is several times activated. First with an HTTP_ACCEPT environ parameter set to text/html and after that: several image/webp requests and one text/css request. I understand the first one. But the others should not be directed to the application but get images and css files from the static folder. Why?